# syslog-ng process cannot write to folder, but user can

Tags: linux, nfs, system-administration, uid, syslog-ng

We have an NFS mount as a destination for our log files.  I have syslog-ng running as root out of simplicity.

I have the NFS share mounted, and can, by-hand, create files and directories.  But syslog-ng is throwing an error saying that it cannot write to files in that NFS share.

But syslog-ng is running as root.  So I as the root user can create these files by hand, but a process running as root cannot.

Anyone have any experience in this?  Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

So after digging, I found that this was an SELinux issue on the client side.

Apparently, as clients join an NFS server/mount, the local SELinux policy on the client can block the writing of syslog to the NFS mount because the NFS mount is sitting outside of /var/log.

Turning SELinux off on the client solved the problem.  So an SELinux policy/context will have to be created around syslog/syslog-ng in order to turn SELinux back on.